# Zum, zur und zun?

Tags: preposition, article, contractions

In German you abbreviate `zu der` as `zur` and `zu dem` as `zum`.

Why does the abbreviation `zun` for `zu den` does not exist?

Comment: It is always good to judge what you are told but I think there is no end to ask this "Why" questions.

Comment: In the Berlin dialect "zun [ˈtsuːn̩]" exists https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlinische_Grammatik

Comment: Why is it bad to ask why? Maybe there is an easy explanation why it does not exist. Or is it better to ask why do you abbreviate `zu der` as `zur`?

Comment: Because in this case, your *Why?* can probably only be answered by *Because.*...

Comment: Next question: Why the heck do we abbreviate `in dem` as `im` and `in das` as `ins`, but not `in den` as `inn`?
Or `an dem` as `am` and `an das` as `ans`, but not `an den` as `ann`?
Maybe our ancestors just hated referring to (accusative) plural objects? ;-)

Comment: Maybe they just found they simply had no need for these shortcuts?

Comment: You see that there is a correlation with this forms. And maybe this has a known reason.

Comment: @landunder I did not say that it is bad to ask why. I meant the languages were developed naturally although there were some very minor interventations by language comittee etc. However, in most cases, you cannot find a reasonable answer here because nobody cannot know it. They can only guess it. It is similar to ask "Why does Germany take *das* as an article, while Switzerland takes *die*?" or "Why is table called as *Tisch* instead of Handy?".

Comment: +1 for Berlin dialect. The band 'KNORKATOR' from Berlin wrote a song called `Ick wer zun Schwein`. That means `Ich werde zu einem Schwein`

Comment: @oliholz this is not a good example because it doesn't mean `Ich werde zu einen Schwein`. Better example is `Ich gehe zun Menschen` for `Ich gehe zu den Menschen`.

Comment: @oliholz +1 for mentioning *Knorkator* =3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*zum* and *zur* are contractions **not** of High German *zu dem* and *zu der*. These contractions existed before there was High German, and they have been contracted from dialectal forms.

***zur*** is contracted from *zu dər*

> *I gang zu dər Dier.* => *I gang zur Dier.* "Ich gehe zu der Tür."

***zum*** is contracted from *zu em*

> *I gang zu em Doar.* => *I gang zum Doar.* "Ich gehe zu dem Tor."

So what does that mean for *zun*? In the Middle and Upper German dialects, from which High German was created, *den* was not shortened to *en*, which would have allowed speakers to contract it to *zun*, rather it was shortened to *də*:

**<strike>*zun*</strike>** cannot be contracted from *zu də*

> *I gang zu də Kind.* => [no further contraction] "Ich gehe zu den Kindern."

There are some dialects (or [metrolects](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrolekt)), as @Iris has pointed out in a comment, that do contract *zu den* to either *zu(ə)n* or *zune*. But these are dialects that had no or little part in the formation of High German.